# Error with LinearFit in geographical line

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a set of pixels that follow a straight line.  However, the values aren't all clearly visible.  I want to create a Line Feature that I can later use to identify it.

I have created a Lon Lat image and have masked it with the value of my pixels so that only the Pixels of interest have a value.  It should be quite simple, having 'longitude' and 'latitude' as bands to create a linear fit of these geographical points.  [firstLine](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/JASPR/firstLine/firstline)

However, when I try to do a linear fit of this cloud of points I receive an error.  (Code is below)

```
Image.reduce: ReduceBands reducer must have one input: LINEAR_FIT.
```

[image: Line of treetops]

```
var lonLat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat();

var myMask = myPixelLine;

var firstLine = lonLat.updateMask(myMask);

var linearFit = firstLine.select(['longitude','latitude'])
                            .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit());
```